# Bitcoin core почему RPC открыт только для localhost?

Tags: bitcoin, rpc

Не получается соеденится с RPC Bitcoin Node, вернее с localhost все нормально, а вот из другого сервера - ошибка:

`curl: (7) Failed to connect to server_ip port 8331: Connection refused`

Как открыть доступ из вне?

Тут видно что порт который указан в конфиге `8331` открыт только для localhost

`lsof -i | grep LISTEN`

```
systemd-r 268 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  13475      0t0  TCP localhost:domain (LISTEN)
sshd      469            root    3u  IPv4  15137      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd      469            root    4u  IPv6  15148      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
bitcoind  532            root    9u  IPv6  15735      0t0  TCP localhost:8331 (LISTEN)
bitcoind  532            root   10u  IPv4  15737      0t0  TCP localhost:8331 (LISTEN)
bitcoind  532            root   27u  IPv6  15772      0t0  TCP *:8333 (LISTEN)
bitcoind  532            root   28u  IPv4  15773      0t0  TCP *:8333 (LISTEN)
```

Вот мой `bitcoin.conf`:

```
server=1
daemon=1
maxconnections=20
prune=551
dbcache=300
dbbatchsize=1024
maxsigcachesize=4
maxmempool=300
maxorphantx=10
mempoolexpiry=12
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=pass
rpcallowip=site_ip
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
rpcport=8331
whitelist=site_ip
whitelist=127.0.0.1
whitelist=0.0.0.0/0
```

Тестирую в терминале командой: `curl --data-binary '{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"curltext","method":"getnewaddress","params":[]}' -H 'content-type:text/plain;' http://user:pass@server_ip:8331`

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен созданием тоннеля на сервере с сайтом к серверу где биткоин

`/usr/bin/ssh -NT -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -L 127.0.0.1:8332:127.0.0.1:8332 tunnel@IP_SERVER_BTC`